# Convert CSV to JSON with python and split the csv with seperator "|"

Tags: python, json, csv

```
schoolname|category|gender|medium_of_inst|address|area|pincode|landmark
----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+------
qqq|qqq|qq|aa|asd|wer|asd|wert
www|fgh|qq|aa|sg|wer|asd|wert
eee|fxg|qq|aa|axcvsd|wer|asd|wert
```

How can I remove the second line and split "|" and convert it to json

Comment: What do u mean by "|" ? Can u show your CSV?

Comment: The format of the CSV is in the question, I need it to convert to json

Comment: @Praveen did you try the below code in the answer and is working?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. First split the string by `\n` and remove the second line and then split by `|`. Hope this will help.

```
import json

strings = '''schoolname|category|gender|medium_of_inst|address|area|pincode|landmark
----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+------
qqq|qqq|qq|aa|asd|wer|asd|wert
www|fgh|qq|aa|sg|wer|asd|wert
eee|fxg|qq|aa|axcvsd|wer|asd|wert'''

json_file_name = 'test.json'

strings = strings.split('\n') #Split the string by newline \n
del strings[0] #Remove the heading columns
del strings[0] #Remove the string starts with ----------+
data = []

try:
  for string in strings:
    row = string.split('|') #Split and write to json 
    row_data = {};
    row_data['schoolname'] = row[0]
    row_data['category'] = row[1]
    row_data['gender'] = row[2]
    row_data['medium_of_inst'] = row[3]
    row_data['address'] = row[4]
    row_data['area'] = row[5]
    row_data['pincode'] = row[6]
    row_data['landmark'] = row[7]
    data.append(row_data)

  with open(json_file_name, 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)

  #Use the below to read the file  
  with open(json_file_name) as file_object:
    # store file data in object
    data = json.load(file_object)
    print(data)

except Exception as e:
      print("Type error: " + str(e))
```

**Output**

```
[
  {
    'schoolname': 'qqq',
    'category': 'qqq',
    'gender': 'qq',
    'medium_of_inst': 'aa',
    'address': 'asd',
    'area': 'wer',
    'pincode': 'asd',
    'landmark': 'wert'
  },
  {
    'schoolname': 'www',
    'category': 'fgh',
    'gender': 'qq',
    'medium_of_inst': 'aa',
    'address': 'sg',
    'area': 'wer',
    'pincode': 'asd',
    'landmark': 'wert'
  },
  {
    'schoolname': 'eee',
    'category': 'fxg',
    'gender': 'qq',
    'medium_of_inst': 'aa',
    'address': 'axcvsd',
    'area': 'wer',
    'pincode': 'asd',
    'landmark': 'wert'
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here below is the snippet which would help you :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test_old.csv',skiprows=2, 
  names=['schoolname', 'category', 'gender','medium_of_inst',
         'address','area','pincode','landmark'],   
       sep='|', engine='python')

json_output = df.to_json(orient='records')[1:-1].replace('},{', '} {')

print(json_output)
```

Output :

[
   {
      "schoolname":"qqq",
      "category":"qqq",
      "gender":"qq",
      "medium_of_inst":"aa",
      "address":"asd",
      "area":"wer",
      "pincode":"asd",
      "landmark":"wert"
   },
   {
      "schoolname":"www",
      "category":"fgh",
      "gender":"qq",
      "medium_of_inst":"aa",
      "address":"sg",
      "area":"wer",
      "pincode":"asd",
      "landmark":"wert"
   },
   {
      "schoolname":"eee",
      "category":"fxg",
      "gender":"qq",
      "medium_of_inst":"aa",
      "address":"axcvsd",
      "area":"wer",
      "pincode":"asd",
      "landmark":"wert"
   }
]